# Location tracking using triangulation

Tags: android, ios, wifi, triangulation

I have a double question regarding location tracking using triangulation (over wifi signal).

1. Does it also work outdoors?
2. Does it work on wifi networks that are protected? What I mean is that in Belgium, our different ISP's provide hotspot functionality which are only accessible when you are a customer. Is using the wifi signal always possible as soon as it is available? Or does it also require authentication before it can be made use of?

Edit: Do you know of some good and clear documentation/references on how to learn how to implement it for Android / iOS?

Comment: Yes and yes, fused location is already using a combination of cell, wifi and gps to obtain position, selecting the best available provider. I can recommend this library for Android https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation. Indoor location is a different story, and is a rather big topic in ubiquitous computer research. To get reliable location it usually involves building a radio map of the building, or creating fingerprints of selected areas.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Many thanks.

Comment: On a side note to your Questions which have been answered by a couple people, you should research [Trilateration](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Trilateration). As long as you know the co-ordinations (location) of each Wifi Router, you can create a Trilateration algorithm that will determine the location of where the user is depending on how strong the signal is from each Wifi Router (you create another algorithm that determines distance OR you just take the signal strength and do it that way)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For iOS**

> Does it also work outdoors?

Yes, if there is WiFi signal

> Does it work on wifi networks that are protected? What I mean is that
>   in Belgium, our different ISP's provide hotspot functionality which
>   are only accessible when you are a customer. Is using the wifi signal
>   always possible as soon as it is available? Or does it also require
>   authentication before it can be made use of?

It does not require authentication. Not sure what networks it is using, but in cities it can be surprisingly accurate.

> Edit: Do you know of some good and clear documentation/references on
>   how to learn how to implement it for Android / iOS?

On iOS you just use the same API you use for GPS tracking - [CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html). It uses appropriate technology based on capabilities of the device and required accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Example for Android

```
final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String networkOperator = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
int mcc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(0, 3));
int mnc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(3));
String operatorName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
final GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
int lac = cellLocation.getLac();
```